# SQL Server 2005 - using generated sequences instead of Identity columns?

Tags: sql-server-2005, identity, sequence

I'm really thinking about switching away from Identity columns in SQL Server 2005 and going with some type of sequence generator (as far as I know there's nothing built in to 2005 to do this; may be coming in 2011?) to get unique id's for inserted rows.

Is there a model implementation or best practice for this? Will I encounter locking issues? What are the down sides compared to just using Identity columns?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the impetus to move away from identity columns? What is your pain?

Comment: Mostly doing some big db changes and need to update their values.

Comment: And how would having a sequence table help?

Comment: If you are going to make big DB changes and need to UPDATE values... I can't see how you conclude you DON'T want identities... if that what they're for... If you ever need to update Identities you can always use SET IDENTITY_INSERT and the DBCC command.

Comment: identity_insert doesn't work with updates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, SQL 11 has SEQUENCE objects, see [SQL Server v.Next (Denali) : Using SEQUENCE](https://sqlblog.org/2010/11/11/sql-server-v-next-denali-using-sequence).

Creating manual sequences is possible, but not recommended. The trick to do a sequence generator is to use UPDATE WITH OUTPUT on a sequences table. Here is pseudo-code:

```
CREATE TABLE Sequences (
    Name sysname not null primary key, 
    Sequence bigint not null default 0);
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_getSequence
    @name sysname,
    @value bigint output
AS
    UPDATE Sequences
    SET Sequence = Sequence + 1
     OUTPUT @value = INSERTED.Sequence
    WHERE Name = @name;
GO
```

I left out some details, but this is the general idea. However, there is a huge problem: any transaction requesting the next value on a sequence will **lock** that sequence until it commits, because it will place an update lock on the sequence value. This means that *all* transactions have to serialize after each other when inserting values and the performance degradation that results is unbearable in real production deployments.

I would much rather have you stick with the IDENTITY types. While not perfect, they are far better than what you can achieve on your own.

Comment: Does this work reliably with any Transaction isolation level, or do you need a minimum level for this to work even under heavy concurrency load?? I'm asking since the current solution I have inherited utilizes a cursor (!!! and not even `FAST_FORWARD`) to do this.... seems a bit like overkill....

Comment: @marc_s with a clustered index on `Name` it should work under all isolation levels. Under heavy load it should produce correct results, but heavy contention: only one transaction can produce a sequence at a time.

Answer (score 2):

The way that i used to solve this problem was a table 'Sequences' that stores all my sequences and a 'nextval' stored procedure.

Sql Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Sequences (  
    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,  
    value BIGINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,  
    CONSTRAINT PK_Sequences PRIMARY KEY (name)  
);
```

The **PK_Sequences** is used just to be sure that there will never be sequences with the same name.

Sql Stored Procedure:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'nextVal') AND type in (N'P', N'PC')) DROP PROCEDURE nextVal;  
GO  
CREATE PROCEDURE nextval  
    @name VARCHAR(30)  
AS  
    BEGIN  
        DECLARE @value BIGINT  
        BEGIN TRANSACTION  
            UPDATE Sequences  
            SET @value=value=value + 1  
            WHERE name = @name;  
            -- SELECT @value=value FROM Sequences WHERE name=@name  
        COMMIT TRANSACTION  
        SELECT @value AS nextval  
    END;
```

Insert some sequences:

```
INSERT INTO Sequences(name, value) VALUES ('SEQ_Workshop', 0);
INSERT INTO Sequences(name, value) VALUES ('SEQ_Participant', 0);
INSERT INTO Sequences(name, value) VALUES ('SEQ_Invoice', 0);
```

Finally get next value of a sequence,

```
execute nextval 'SEQ_Participant';
```

Some c# code to get the next value from Sequence table,

```
public long getNextVal()
{
    long nextval = -1;
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("your connection string");
    try
    {
        // Connect and execute the select sql command.
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("nextval", connection);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "SEQ_Participant";
        nextval = Int64.Parse(command.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

        command.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception) { }
    finally
    {
        connection.Dispose();
    }
    return nextval;
}
```