# serialising rows in a table

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, asp-classic

I have a table which contains header information for transactions. The transactions belong to different projects.

In the header I have columns:

```
rhguid - uniqueidentifier
rhserial - int
rh_projectID - int
```

First I insert the row (there's more columns)

Then I calculate the serial number for that project:

```
update responseheader 
set rhSerial = 1 + (select isnull(max(rhSerial), 0) 
                    from responseheader 
                    where (rhstatus = 0) AND (rh_projectID = 1234)) 
where 
   (rhGUID = <preassignedGUID>);
```

However when there are many transactions happening at the same time for a project I am finding duplicate `rhserial` values.

I'm doing this in classic ASP with SQL Server 2008.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Couldn't you just make the `rhserial` column an `INT IDENTITY` column and leave the increasing of the sequential number to SQL Server altogether? That's really the best way to go - no hassle and no fuss on your side - just let SQL Server do the work

Comment: No because each project needs its own run of serial numbers. So project 1234 will have rhserials from 1 upwards. And project 1235 will also have rhserials from 1 upwards. rhserial is not unique across the table.

Comment: In that case, you need to have (1) a table with the current serial numbers for each project, and (2) a thread- and concurrency-safe method (e.g. stored procedure) to get the next valid number for each project from that "serial-no table". Just using `SELECT MAX()+1` is **not** safe under load. [See this other SO question and the answer by Remus Rusanu showing how to do this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083846/sql-server-2005-using-generated-sequences-instead-of-identity-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example, it doesn't look like you're using a transaction.  My guess is that the SELECT portion of the statement is running as **READ UNCOMMITTED**, otherwise you would not see duplicates.  There are ways to start transactions with ADO, but I prefer using stored procedures instead.

Try implementing something like this:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.ResponseHeader_Insert
  <more data to insert>,
  @ProjectID INT,
  @Status SMALLINT
as

insert responseheader (column names here)
select <param values here>, isnull(max(rhSerial), 0) + 1
from responseheader  
where (rhstatus = @Status) AND (rh_projectID = @ProjectID))
```

If this doesn't work for ya, try creating sequence tables (one for each sequence).

```
create table <tablename> (
      SeqID int identity(1,1) primary key,
      SeqVal varchar(1)
)
```

Create a procedure to get the next identity:

```
create procedure GetNewSeqVal_<tablename>
as
begin
      declare @NewSeqValue int

      set NOCOUNT ON

      insert into <tablename> (SeqVal) values ('a')
      set @NewSeqValue = scope_identity()
      delete from <tablename> WITH (READPAST)
return @NewSeqValue
end
```

If there are too many sequence tables that need to be created or you want to create sequences on the fly, try this approach:

```
Create table AllSequences (
      SeqName nvarchar(255) primary key, -- name of the sequence
      Seed int not null default(1), -- seed value
      Incr int not null default(1), -- incremental
      Currval int 
)
Go

create procedure usp_CreateNewSeq
      @SeqName nvarchar(255),
      @seed int = 0,
      @incr int = 1
as

begin

      declare @currval int
      if exists (
            select 1 from AllSequences
            where SeqName = @SeqName )

      begin
            print 'Sequence already exists.'
            return 1    
      end

      if @seed is null set @seed = 1
      if @incr is null set @incr = 1
      set @currval = @seed

      insert into AllSequences (SeqName, Seed, Incr, CurrVal)
      values (@SeqName, @Seed, @Incr, @CurrVal)
end
go


create procedure usp_GetNewSeqVal

      @SeqName nvarchar(255)
as

begin
      declare @NewSeqVal int
      set NOCOUNT ON

      update AllSequences
      set @NewSeqVal = CurrVal = CurrVal+Incr
      where SeqName = @SeqName

      if @@rowcount = 0 begin
            print 'Sequence does not exist'
            return
      end
      return @NewSeqVal
end
go
```

Comment: the first stored procedure method might work best as there are thousands of independent sequences of unknown length. Your SP uses an insert (presumably of the whole row) rather than an insert and then an update. Does being in an SP overcome the transaction problem? Thanks

Comment: @derekcohen, not by itself, but it's easier.  Look at Begin Tran/Commit Tran.  The reason I didn't add begin/commit tran in the first stored proc is because there's only one insert statement. You could do the same with ADO and not worry about creating a transaction.  You're original query was an insert/update (2 statements).  To run those in a single transaction you would have to use begin/commit tran, or start a transaction with ADO.