# SQL Server dependent Identity - is there such a thing?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I use SQL Server 2008 R2.

I'm looking for a feature that I describe as dependent identity.

I'll explain by an example.

consider a table like this one:

script

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Rooms](
    [RoomID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ItemID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ItemDescription] [nvarchar] (250))
GO
```

data:

```
RoomID  ItemID  ItemDescription
------  ------  --------------- 
7       1       Door
7       2       Window (West)
7       3       Window (North)
8       1       Door
8       2       Table #1
8       3       Table #2
7       4       Table #1 
8       4       Chair #1 
7       5       Table #2 
7       6       Table #3 
8       5       Chair #2
```

(can anyone tell the secret how to format an example table here?)

I would have love to be able to declare a dependent identity column like this:

`ItemID [int] Identity(RoomID,1,1) NOT NULL`

A new row in `[Rooms]` should triggers a test for the max value of `ItemID` where `RoomID` = `@roomID` and add 1.

Instead of update with a change in `RoomID` use delete and insert the required data.

Nowadays I do that programmatically like this:

```
DECLARE @roomID INT
SET @roomID = 7
INSERT INTO [Allocation].[dbo].[Rooms]
    ([RoomID], [ItemID], [ItemDescription]) VALUES (@roomID,
    (SELECT max([ItemID])+1 FROM [Allocation].[dbo].[Rooms] WHERE [RoomID]=@roomID)
    ,'Chair #1')
GO
```

So, Is there such a feature?

In the probable case there is none, could I program the server to set next dependent identity for me automatically, given a specific table, parent column and dependent identity column?

Comment: Currently, in SQL Server 2008 R2 - no, unfortunately. With SQL Server **2012**, we'll get [sequences](https://sqlblog.org/2010/11/11/sql-server-v-next-denali-using-sequence) which could be something of a help - it's like a "stand-alone" `IDENTITY` , not bound to a table's column.

Comment: Getting "manual" sequences right isn't as easy as selecting `MAX(ID)+1` from your table - such an approach is guaranteed to generate duplicates in an even moderately busy system.

Getting this right, with the proper locking and transaction handling is a science - one that Remus Rusanu has perfected and [shown in this answer to a previous SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083846/sql-server-2005-using-generated-sequences-instead-of-identity-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a trigger, and an index to improve performance and ensure there are no duplicates.

Change your table to have a primary key, and allow null for ItemID

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Rooms](
    [RoomID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ItemID] [int] NULL,
    [ItemDescription] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Rooms] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Id] ASC
    )
)
```

and then add a trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER RoomTrigger
   ON  Rooms
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    update Rooms
    set 
        ItemID = (select coalesce(MAX(itemid), 0) + 1 
                      from Rooms r where r.RoomID = inserted.RoomID )
    from
        inserted where Rooms.Id = inserted.Id

END
```

Then you can do this

```
insert into Rooms (RoomID, ItemDescription) values (1, 'Test')
insert into Rooms (RoomID, ItemDescription) values (1, 'Test')
```

which results in

```
RoomID  ItemID ItemDescription Id
2       0      Test            1
2       1      Test            2
```

As suggested by marc_s I've used SQL Query Stress with 10 threads to see what happens with this trigger under load. I didn't get any duplicates at all (using the default isolation level), but I did get loads of deadlocks as I would have expected.

Using the original query from the question I get a lot of duplicates.

Using the trigger approach I get deadlocks and results like this:

```
RoomID ItemID ItemDescription Id
1      6      Test            6
1      7      Test            9
1      8      Test            902
1      9      Test            903
```

Here ItemID is contiguous, but about 900 out of 1000 rows failed to be inserted leaving large gaps in Id.

If we add the following index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Rooms] ON [dbo].[Rooms] 
(
    [RoomID] ASC,
    [ItemID] ASC
)
```

in order to guarantee no duplicates, and improve the performance of calculating Max(ItemId) for a particular RoomID, then now:

- the original query from the question causes duplicates and only manages to insert 500 rows.
- the trigger version using the default isolation level succeeds **without any deadlocks or errors** and runs very fast.

Using the trigger with isolation level = serializable brings back deadlocks so only 40% of the inserts succeed (but no exceptions due to duplicates).

As a final test tried with trigger + 50 threads + isolation level = default.  **No errors**.

Comment: This is absolutely **NOT SAFE** under load.... if you have even fairly light loads, you'll get **duplicates** for that new `ItemID` - don't do this. See my comment to the original question with a link to an answer to a previous SO question that shows how to properly do this, safely, and without duplicates

Comment: @marc_s: I could understand this resulting in locking issues.  But are you sure that it would result in duplicates if the isolation level was serializable?

Comment: marc_s- I do not see how duplicates may happen, but I do see how the trigger updates the same last insert twice. @Phil- I've change the ItemID to start with 1 and it works. How can I be sure that if two users insert a line at almost the same time I won't miss insert statements? Let's say user1 insert a row and before the trigger fires another user inserts another row. Am I wrong and the trigger will not fire twice for the last insert? In other words, is it possible to link between the insert and the trigger to run together? How to isolate insert and trigger together?

Comment: if you're using SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE there shouldn't be a problem with duplicates - but I'm happy to be proved wrong.

Comment: @Phil- but how can I do that? I can write this before the insert, and release with `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED`. I do not think it will catch the trigger. If not releasing, what is the difference between that and not isolating? Inserts will still be able to run after another and the trigger can still fire twice on the last insert, right?

Comment: Go grab [SQL Query Stress](http://www.datamanipulation.net/sqlquerystress/) by Adam Machanic - and simulate 5, 10, 20 clients inserting rows at the same time. You will get duplicates - guaranteed.

Comment: @marc_s see updated answer - no problem when using trigger + index

Comment: @Phil - Hi, I'm using your answer, and I have this little problem you may be able to solve. Your answer do everything well, but from time, when many concurrent users insert rows,  some rows are switch dependent keys. i.e the 'moving' 'current' last inserted record may get the seconds higher dependent key, and the current seconds last record gets the higher dependent key value. Can you understand what the problem is?

Comment: @Different111222.  I'm not sure, but it maybe down to isolation level.  Try changing to REPEATABLE READ in place of READ COMMITTED. However this may end up causing lots of deadlocks as experienced with SERIALIZABLE.

Comment: @phil - You were right. Raising the isolation one level does not help, and even cause more keys/dependent-keys switches. Raising two levels up caused deadlocks. Lowering one level reduces switches, but they are still created. Starting raised isolation level before the insert and moving back to the default isolation level at the end of the trigger causes deadlocks (all inserts did not commit!). I do not see a way out, but thanks anyways.