# How to force after insert trigger to execute just after its insert, before any other insert is executed?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

This problem is about concurrent high speed inserts.
I must admit it is very interesting in my eyes.

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 executing T-SQL inserts and after insert trigger.

I would like to make sure that no command will execute between an insert and its after insert trigger.

Using isolation levels causes deadlocks or just does **NOT** solve the problem.

The procedure I'm using is the answer/solution from Phil to 
[SQL Server dependent Identity - is there such a thing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769780/sql-server-dependent-identity-is-there-such-a-thing)

The problem is:

sometimes an insert get in between a previous insert and its after insert trigger, causing this result:

```
RoomID  ItemID  ItemDescription ID
------  ------  --------------- --
7       1       Door             1
7       2       Window (West)    2
7       3       Window (North)   3
8       1       Door             4
8       2       Table #1         5
8       3       Table #2         6
7       4       Table #1         7
8       4       Chair #1         8
7       6       Table #2         9
7       5       Table #3        10
8       5       Chair #2        11
```

See IDs #9 and #10. Thair ItemIDs are switched. The ItemID should have been 5 and 6 respectively and not 6 and 5, but the 10th insert probably occurred before the after insert trigger of #9 finished execution.

This problem happens less than 0.5% of the inserts: 2 switches involving 4 records for 1000 inserts or less. Yes, sometimes there are no switches occurrences.

Raising the isolation level by one step does not help, and even cause more keys/dependent-keys switches from time to time. Raising two isolation levels up caused deadlocks.

Lowering the isolation level reduces switches, but they are still created.

Starting raised isolation level before the every insert and moving back to the default isolation level at the end of the trigger causes deadlocks (in my experiments all inserts did not commit!).

Do anyone see a way out?

How to force an insert and its after insert trigger to execute together, prohibiting other inserts to the same table in between?

Comment: It's unclear to me what ItemID is or does. Can you use a calculated column to find it, instead of an `after` trigger?

Comment: Also, in SQL 2012, you could use a sequence.

Comment: Can you show us... `1` the table before the inserts.  `2` the inserts thmeselves, and their order.  `3` the code in the trigger.

Comment: @dems - May start with empty table (not a must). Many insert trials placed almost at the same time. e.g, the insert includes the RoomID and ItemDescription (it's a drop down - no mistakes, no codes and no importance, my be null) (forget about the ItemDescription, it is not important an insert like `INSERT Rooms (RoomID) VALUES (1)` is more than enough for the example. The trigger code is exactly as the source solution: `update Rooms set  ItemID = (select coalesce(MAX(itemid), 0) + 1 from Rooms r where r.RoomID = inserted.RoomID ) from inserted where Rooms.Id = inserted.Id`. This is it. Thanks.

Comment: @david-manheim - ItemID is a dependent identity. it is a serial number like of inserts for the same RoomID. The order is important due to rights. I'm bounded to Sql 2008 R2 at the moment. Thanks.

Comment: You want exactly what @thecoon suggests.  An instead of trigger.  In such a trigger the `inserted` table is still populated, but the records do not yet exist in the target table.  You insert them in to your table in the trigger (instead of using UPDATE), see the link in his answer.

Comment: @Different111222: Which approach did you choose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using an [instead of insert trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175089%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)?

Of course, you will have to make the actual insert yourself, but that's the supported behavior in SQL Server. There are no *before insert triggers* or something similar.

Anyway, you can still use your current trigger processing logic in this type of trigger as well.

To try and imagine a better solution, can you explain what you you are trying to do? Are multiple threads inserting in this table? Is this a real-time process?

> It's auction like. Yes, multiple threads are inserting in this table.
>   The problem is rear but happens. No reasons for complaints yet, but
>   there may be (the switches happened by now where not at the critical
>   point). Users who initiate inserts need to know what is their
>   precedence in a list of orders. The ItemID is used almost imminently,
>   therefore, may not be calculated on the fly (with select count(*)...
>   where..) later on when needed a matter of milliseconds. Wrong order of
>   ItemID may cause losses to one and non rightful gains for another.

Well, multithreaded inserts are almost never a good idea in SQL server. At least not without some sort of synchronization.

You need some kind of queuing. 
For example, I have a similar system where need to insert between 2.5-3 million records  per day (well, working hours).

At first I also used 8-16 threads to do my inserts directly on the database. And I noticed exactly this behavior: deadlocks. So I start thinking about how I could queue these messages so only 1 thread (1 connection) will be inserting at any time.

I ended up queuing these records in MSMQ (transactional). Some other process comes and takes them from here (also transactional) and inserts them in batches in the database. My records are guaranteed to come in the correct order, the one in which they were sent.

So this secondary process inserts batches of records and, as you, I need some pre-processing before inserting, which I'm doing with an instead-of-insert trigger. There I can update the entire `inserted` table "quietly", without worrying that someone can come and mess my stuff.

It's just an idea. You may also want to consider Service Broker for queuing, especially if you don't want to take the processing outside SQL Server.

Also, something worth trying are transactions with [Snapshot Isolation level and row versioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcbchxcb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), but I recommend going the MSMQ/Service Broker way.

Comment: It's auction like. Yes, multiple threads are inserting in this table. The problem is rear but happens. No reasons for complaints yet, but there may be (the switches happened by now where not at the critical point). Users who initiate inserts need to know what is their precedence in a list of orders. The ItemID is used almost imminently, therefore, may not be calculated on the fly (with select count(*)... where..) later on when needed a matter of milliseconds. Wrong order of ItemID may cause losses to one and non rightful gains for another.

Comment: @Different111222 - Follow the link this answer provides.  Use `INSTEAD OF` triggers rather than `AFTER` triggers.

Comment: @Different111222: Updated answer with an alternative (two actually).