# Handling incrementing number with DB

Tags: sql-server-2008

We have a requirement that says that when ever we get a new person into a database, we need to assign them a unique number. This number will start from a defined number when the system goes live. So, if the client say, "Start at 500,000!", then the first allocated ID will be 500000.

Easy - Auto increment fiend.

However, this `ID` is the `Account Number` which is sent to an external client for linking the person to an account. An idea may have been to use the auto inc primary key, but I believe it's poor to use the PK as an external facing 'person number'.

Someone mentioned having a table, with an auto inc pk, and an id to the person table that we're adding the number to. But that seems strange.

My idea is to add a new column to our `settings` table, which really only has one row, and contains system settings for the system. The column would be an `INT`, and be called `NextAvailableId`. The rows all have a `Version` column, which is a `Timestamp` (`RowVersion`).

My plan is to create a function called `GetNextId` or something, which would simply do the following:

1. Create a variable called `@AssignedID`
2. Create a variable called `@Version`
3. Get the `NextAvailableId` from the settings table, as well as the version.
4. `Set AssignedID = NextAvailableId`
5. Update the settings table, setting `NextAvailableId  = AssignedID + 1 WHERE version = @Version`
6. Check the updated row count. If it's 1, then we managed to get the latest ID, increment it, and save it back to the table, before another process took an ID.
7. If the updated row count was zero - then someone grabbed a number before us... so, try again, until we have an updated row.

Does that sounds like a safe and valid plan for assigning 'Account Numbers' to my person?

Please note, its no really a person, or an account code. It's a Vendor ID that needs to be applied to a person in order to get stored in a separate system. Just using Person and Account as a (poor) example.

What I need to do is find a way to handle the unique allocation of 'Account Numbers'. If the manual way is a bad idea, and there is a better way - then that would help me a lot.

Comment: If you choose to use your own *manual* incrementing scheme, you must make **absolutely sure** that your incrementing function is **concurrency safe** even under heavy load. And that's **not easy** to accomplish!

Comment: Thanks @marc_s. Yeah, that's what I am trying to do. So, securing an available ID, using a row version, seems pretty secure to me. But maybe I am missing something? Locking?

Comment: [See this other SO question and Remus Rusanu's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083846/sql-server-2005-using-generated-sequences-instead-of-identity-columns) for how to do it **safely**

Comment: Copy the PK to an external key. Should you ever come into a renumbering situation, is easy to adapt. Use a second table for PK to ext key.

Comment: Joop, can you explain?

Comment: After an INSERT use getGeneratedKeys() to get the PK, and add a mapping table PK-value to external key, both the same value. Should in the future come certain requests of excluding a range, or whatever, you can adapt the algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Although I do not agree to your approach of manually increment the last ID, I do agree with marc_s that you need to pay attention to concurrency.

The quickest way I will do that is to combine transactions within your function with `READ UNCOMMITTED` as isolation level and a small [Mutex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion) field. Here is the pseudo code:

1. Start new transaction with READ UNCOMMITED
2. Check is Mutex flag = 0 (no other method running)
3. If flag = 1, loop
4. If flag = 0, set to 1
5. Get the last ID
6. Increment as you wish
7. Set last ID back in table
8. Set Mutex flag back to 0
9. Return new ID / Commit transaction

`READ UNCOMMITED` will allow multiple executions to check the value of the Mutex flag while other transactions are still running and not commited yet.

**EDIT :**

I recommend you add a new column with a default value that you use instead of your PK. Example as follow:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetLastId()
RETURNS INT
AS
    BEGIN
        RETURN SELECT MAX(AccountID) + 1 FROM dbo.tblUsers
    END

-- Set the default value to the column
ALTER TABLE dbo.tblUsers
ADD AccountID SET DEFAULT (dbo.GetLastId())
```

Comment: The questioner asked about if it is a safe approach or not. Concurrency is a bad side of his idea

Comment: Maybe something about it being a bad idea should be in your answer.

Comment: Thanks - "Although I do not agree to your approach of manually increment the last ID". The only other thing I can think of is using an auto increment - but for some reason, I am worried that this isn't the right approach either.

Comment: @Craig: the auto-increment would relieve you from having to worry about concurrency-safety - it does that for you, for "free" so to speak...

Comment: Thanks @marc_s... Yeah, I hear what you're saying. I'm jusy wondering how to apply it. Jut use a 'Ids' type table, add the 'PersonID' to it, and then use the primary key of that table as my 'PersonNumber'? Sounds like a much easier and safer way - but not sure of the best design.